# FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting this warning in Python 2.7.12 + numpy 1.11.1, and the function [setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html).

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
a = [45, 2, -5, 6, 7, 88]
b = [12, 8, 36, 125, 9, -62, 1]

c = np.setdiff1d(a, b.sort())

...python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:375: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  mask &= (ar1 != a)
```

There are other questions about this warning in SO, bu they all seem to use `None` explicitly, while I do not.

Why is this warning showing, and how can I fix my code so that it does not?

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but shouldn't that be `np.setdiff1d(a, np.sort(b))` instead, because `b.sort()` is in-place sorting?

Comment: `b.sort()`  is an inplace operation. It returns None. Maybe you want `sorted(b)`?

Comment: Yes, you are both correct. I didn't realize I was performing an in place sorting. This question seems dumb now.